# Does install another version of Ubuntu can solve the problem that "No wifi adapter found"?

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, lenovo, adapter

my Ubuntu version is 18.04

levonvo 330-15IKB (Type 81DE) Laptop (ideapad) - Type 81DE

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: I don't know which Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you tried, but you could also try a different HWE kernel (esp. 18.04.3 LTS released this very week), but to provide more specific detail I'd have to know the chipset used in your machine (which you didn't provide, prior link tells you how to work this detail out, which also allows search engines & internet to help you find quicker solutions using the release you already have)

Comment: thanks for the response.. i have dual booted my laptop with "ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso" and windows 10. specifications: levonvo 330-15IKB (Type 81DE) Laptop (ideapad) - Type 81DE with intel(r) core(tm) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz with 8gb ram network adapter which is showing in windows 10 is : Realtek 8821CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC